# Get all from table by relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables and an in-between like

| project |
| --- |
| id |

| group |
| --- |
| id |

| project_group |
| --- |
| project |
| group |

How can I get all projects by a `groupId`, where an entry `(projectId, groupId)` exists in `project_group`?

Comment: Note that 'group' is a reserved word in MySQL, making it a poor choice as a table/column identifier. For further help, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry I use <code>`group`</code> and it's fine

Comment: It's not fine. :-|

Comment: @Strawberry what should I change it to?

Comment: my_groups, organisations, collections, anything really

Answer (score -1):

Since only Project_group has information for both project and group it's the only way to relate those two tables. In this scenario we need to join project with group so that we can find a project associated to a particular group.

Let's assume that we need to find all the project associated with group 1. The to select all the project - group relationship for group 1 we can write:

```
select project, group  from project_group where group=1
```

This will return only the relationship but we need all the project related information such as code, name, cost etc.

On the other hand id from project table is same as project from project_group table. So we can join both the table with inner join on those columns as below:

```
select * from project p inner join project_group pg on p.id=pg.group
```

Now we will combine both the queries:

```
select * from project p inner join project_group pg on p.id=pg.group
and pg.group=1
```

It will return all the columns from project and project_group table.
But to have all the columns from only project table you can use:

```
select p.* from project p inner join project_group pg on p.id=pg.group
and pg.group=1
```

Comment: Change "group" name to what?

Comment: any name which is not a reserved word like pgroup.

Comment: I don't think your answer will work, the last inner join confuses me. I know in advance what group I want to filter by

Comment: changed my answer

Comment: your second answer will just return project ids and not projects themselves I think

Comment: but I looked at the flagged duplicate and suspect this will work `SELECT * FROM project p, project_group pg WHERE pg.project = p.id AND pg.group = ?`

Comment: it's same as my changed first answer. if you only want project information then use p.*

Comment: Thanks didn't know about `p.*`

Comment: most welcome. Though I would suggest to use column names seperately like p.id, p.name etc.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried.